# Fill relationships Core Data

Tags: database, xcode, core-data

I´m trying to create new elements in my database. I can fill all the attributes from my new element but I can fill its relatioship. Anybody knows how can I do that??

I fill the new element like that:

```
NSManagedObject *mo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];
[mo setValue:label_name.text forKey:@"name"];
[mo setValue:label_surname.text forKey:@"surname"];
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For to-one relationships, you

1. Create the object that should be related
2. Use `setValue:forKey:` the same as you would for an attribute.

For to-many relationships, you

1. Create the object that should be related
2. Use `mutableSetValueForKey` on the originating object to add the new object to the relationship.

Comment: I´ve also tried this:

    [mo setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:99] forKey:@"Relationship"];
    

And I get:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "Relatioship"; desired type = NSSet; given type = NSCFNumber; value = 99.'


Any idea? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I´ve tried something like this:

 NSManagedObject *mo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity1"   inManagedObjectContext:context];
[mo mutableSetValueForKey:@"Relationship"];  But this appears:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1580.)" UserInfo=0x4d3b380 {NSValidationErrorObject= (entity: Entity1; id: 0x5998ac0 ; data: { Relationship = ( );

Comment: Since this is a to-many relationship, you're on the right track with mutableSetValueForKey. That method gives you an NSMutableSet. You need to add the new object to that set.